# Is there a non-identity monad morphism M ~> M that is monadically natural in M?

Tags: haskell, monads, category-theory

It is known that natural transformations with type signature `a -> a` must be identity functions. This follows from the Yoneda lemma but can be also derived directly. This question asks for the same property but for monad morphisms instead of natural transformations.

Consider monad morphisms `M ~> N` between monads. (These are natural transformations `M a -> N a` that preserve the monad operations on both sides. These transformations are the morphisms in the category of monads.) We can ask whether there exists a monad morphism `e :: (Monad m) => m a -> m a` that works in the same way for every monad `m`. In other words, a monad morphism `e` must be monadically natural in the monad type parameter `m`.

The monadic naturality law says that, for any monad morphism f: M a -> N a between any two monads M and N, we must have  `f . e = e . f` with suitable type parameters.

The question is, can we prove that any such `e` must be an identity function, or is there a counter-example of a non-identity monad morphism `e` defined as

```
  e :: (Monad m) => m a -> m a
  e ma = ...
```

One failed attempt to define such `e` is:

```
 e ma = do
         _ <- ma
         x <- ma
         return x
```

Another failed attempt is

```
 e ma = do
         x <- ma
         _ <- ma
         return x
```

Both these attempts have the correct type signature but fail the monad morphism laws.

It seems that the Yoneda lemma cannot be applied to this case because there are no monad morphisms `Unit ~> M` where `Unit` is the unit monad. I also can't find any proof directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have already exhausted all interesting possibilities. Any `Monad m => m a -> m a` function we might define will inescapably look like this:

```
e :: forall m a. Monad m => m a -> m a
e u = u >>= k
    where
    k :: a -> m a
    k = _
```

In particular, if `k = return`, `e = id`. For `e` not to be `id`, `k` must use `u`  in a nontrivial way (for instance, `k = const u` and `k = flip fmap u . const` amount to your two attempts). In such a case, though, the `u` effects will be duplicated, leading `e` to fail to be a monad morphism for a number of choices of monad `m`. That being so, the only monad morphism fully polymorphic in the monad is `id`.

---

Let's make the argument more explicit.

For the sake of clarity, I will switch to the `join`/`return`/`fmap` presentation for a moment. We want to implement:

```
e :: forall m a. Monad m => m a -> m a
e u = _
```

What can we fill the right hand side with? The most obvious pick is `u`. By itself, that means `e = id`, which doesn't look interesting. However, since we also have `join`, `return` and `fmap`, there is the option of reasoning inductively, with `u` as the base case. Say we have some `v :: m a`, built using the means we have at hand. Besides `v` itself, we have the following possibilities:

1. `join (return v)`, which is `v` and therefore doesn't tell us anything new;
2. `join (fmap return v)`, which is `v` as well; and
3. `join (fmap (\x -> fmap (f x) w) v)`, for some other `w :: m a` built according to our rules, and some `f :: a -> a -> a`. (Adding `m` layers to the type of `f`, as in `a -> a -> m a`, and extra `join`s to remove them wouldn't lead anywhere, as we would then have to show the provenance of those layers, and things would ultimately reduce to the other cases.)

The only interesting case is #3. At this point, I will take a shortcut:

```
join (fmap (\x -> fmap (f x) w) v)
    = v >>= \x -> fmap (f x) w
    = f <$> v <*> w
```

Any non-`u` right hand side, therefore, can be expressed in the form `f <$> v <*> w`, with `v` and `w` being either `u` or further iterations of this pattern, eventually reaching `u`s at the leaves. Applicative expressions of this sort, however, have a canonical form, obtained by using the applicative laws to reassociate all uses of `(<*>)` to the left, which in this case must look like this...

```
c <$> u <*> ... <*> u
```

... with the ellipsis standing for zero or more further occurrences of `u` separated by `<*>`, and `c` being an `a -> ... -> a -> a` function of appropriate arity. Since `a`is fully polymorphic, `c` must, by parametricity, be some `const`-like function which picks one of its arguments. That being so, any such expression can be rewritten in terms of `(<*)` and `(*>)`...

```
u *> ... <* u
```

... with the ellipsis standing for zero or more further occurrences of `u` separated by either `*>` or `<*`, there being no `*>` to the right of a `<*`.

Going back to the start, all non-`id` candidate implementations must look like this:

```
e u = u *> ... <* u
```

We also want `e` to be a monad morphism. As a consequence, it must also be an applicative morphism. In particular:

```
-- (*>) = (>>) = \u v -> u >>= \_ -> v
e (u *> v) = e u *> e v
```

That is:

```
(u *> v) *> ... <* (u >* v) = (u *> ... <* u) *> (v *> ... <* v)
```

We now have a clear path towards a counterexample. If we use the applicative laws to convert both sides to the canonical form, we will (still) end up with interleaved `u`s and `v`s on the left hand side, and with all `v`s after all `u`s on the right hand side. That means the property won't hold for monads like `IO`, `State` or `Writer`, regardless of how many `(*>)` and `(<*)` there are in `e`, or exactly which values are picked by the `const`-like functions on either side. A quick demo:

```
GHCi> e u = u *> u <* u  -- Canonical form: const const <$> u <*> u <*> u
GHCi> e (print 1 *> print 2)
1
2
1
2
1
2
GHCi> e (print 1) *> e (print 2)
1
1
1
2
2
2
```

Comment: I can't find a rigorous enough proof. How can we prove that the effects of `u` will be _necessarily_ duplicated unless `e = id`? (We could also write `e u = do _ <- u; _ <- u; _ <- u; u` and combine further `u`-effects.) How can we describe mathematically  that "a monadic value `p :: m a` has multiple effects copied from `u :: m a`? And then, how can we prove that duplicated (triplicated, etc.) `u`-effects necessarily lead to violations of monad morphism laws?

Comment: @winitzki I have written down my argument more explicitly. The one thinko I had certainly committed in the original revision of the answer was mentioning idempotency, given that the failures I have observed have more to do with commutativity of effects.

Comment: This is interesting. I will have to think some more about it. How can we prove that there is only one way of implementing a nontrivial `e u`, namely using some expression of the form `u *> ... <* u` as you described? Why can't we find some other clever and complicated combination of `fmap`, `return`, and `join`, so that we get something else? It is also a good move to consider applicative morphisms.  It might be easier to prove the analogous property for applicative morphisms than for monad morphisms. (The only applicative morphisms that are applicatively natural are identity morphisms?)

Comment: @winitzki (1) While it'd be nice to have a more crystalline presentation (I'm still thinking about it), I believe my three cases are exhaustive. Only `join _` can lead to a non-`id` result, and #3 is the only way that won't lead to `id` or infinite regress. (2) On `Applicative`: informally, if your only Kleisli arrow is `return`, you aren't using the extra power `Monad` brings, so you might as well work with `Applicative`. (3) Yup, the analogous property holds for applicative morphisms. The part of my argument starting with the canonical form, which is self-contained, should suffice as proof.

Comment: If we had a monad morphism that is monadically natural, we would have also an applicative morphism that is applicatively natural. I think it might be easier to prove that there is no such applicative morphism.

Comment: I have added my answer below where I use a theorem by Jaskelioff and O'Connor. This looks like a more solid argument to me, except for some details that I haven't got time to work out.

Answer (score 1):

Use a theorem by Jaskelioff and O'Connor in the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.1699.pdf where they prove the following identity:

(after Equation 6.1 in section 6)

```
∀(M: Monad). (a → M b) → M c ≅ µ r. c + a × (b → r)
```

However, note that the arrows here (such as `a → M b`) denote ordinary morphisms but not necessarily monad morphisms. We will still need to impose the monad morphisms laws at the end.

We can use the identity above with a = 1, b = c and get:

```
∀(M: Monad). M b → M b ≅ µ r. b + (b → r)
```

We are interested in the following type:

```
∀(b: Type). ∀(M: Monad). M b → M b
```

So we impose the quantifier ∀(b: Type) and get:

```
∀(b: Type). ∀(M: Monad). M b → M b ≅ ∀(b: Type). µ r. b + (b → r)
```

Now it remains to simplify the last type.

This is a longer story and it is written up in another question: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/53855 starting around "Step 3".

The result is the type equivalence:

```
∀(b: Type). µ r. b + (b → r) ≅ 1 + 2 + 3 + ...
```

Values of the type on the right-hand side are pairs of integers `(n, k)` where `n >= k >= 1`. Given a pair `(n, k)`, we write a term `t_{n, k}` of type `∀(b: Type). µ r. b + (b → r)` as:

```
 t_{n, k} = λ(b: Type) → Right( λ(x_1: b) → Right( λ(x_2: b) → ... Right( λ(x_n: b) → Left x_k)...)
```

Here `x_k` is one of the bound variables `x_1`, ..., `x_n` introduced in the term.

So, we get:

```
∀(b: Type). ∀(M: Monad). M b → M b ≅ 1 + 2 + 3 + ...
```

For each term `t_{n, k}`, we now write the corresponding term `e_{n, k}` of type `M b → M b`: (*this remains to be seen in more detail by translating the type equivalence explicitly according to Jaskelioff-O'Connor, but looks plausible* )

```
 e_n_k : Monad m => m b -> m b
 e_n_k mb = do
     _ <- mb  -- line 1
     ...      -- ...
     _ <- mb  -- line k - 1
     x <- mb  -- line k
     _ <- mb  -- line k + 1
     ...      -- ...
     _ <- mb  -- line n
     return x
```

Each pair `(n, k)` corresponds to a unique function of this form, so we can denote those functions by `e_n_k`. So, the Jaskelioff-O'Connor identity shows that all purely parametric functions of type `∀(b: Type). ∀(M: Monad). M b → M b` are of the form `e_n_k` for some `(n, k)`.

It remains to impose the monad morphism laws on `e_n_k`. Then (*I have not found a general proof yet, but it looks correct*) we find that only `e_1_1` (which is an identity function) is a monad morphism while all other `e_n_k` are not monad morphisms.

This concludes the proof that there is only one natural monad morphism of type `∀(b: Type). ∀(M: Monad). M b → M b`. Equivalently, there is only one natural transformation between identity functors in the category of monads.

Comment: I'm also unsure about that "... ≅ 1" you are not certain with. What about λp. p (λ_. p id) ?

Comment: Yes, and actually there are lots of other terms: λp. p x where x : r → r is defined by x = λy. p(λ_. y). We can also compose x with itself, apply x to the final result, etc. -- There is another potential problem with this method of proof: Suppose we find that ∀(r: Type). ((r → r) → r) → r  is not Unit but some other type T. It will follow that ∀(b: Type). ∀(M: Monad). M b → M b = T. But we are asking about the type of monad morphisms, not just any natural transformations. So, we would not have proved that the result is T, only that it is smaller than T.

Comment: I tried to prove the equivalence via parametricity but got stuck. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/53855/can-we-use-relational-parametricity-to-simplify-the-type-forall-a-a-to-a

Comment: @chi I was mistaken. The correct equivalence is most likely ∀(r: Type). ((r → r) → r) → r ≅ 1 + 2 + 3 + ...  , see my answer to this question https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/53855/can-we-use-relational-parametricity-to-simplify-the-type-forall-a-a-to-a/53863 Various values of that type are described by pairs of integers (m, n) and most likely correspond directly to the kind of code shown in my question: do _ <- ma; ...; x <- ma ; ... _ <- ma; return x, where there are m total lines and the n-th line has "x <- ma". I'll have to revise my answer.

Comment: @chi I revised my answer. I think it's close to being a proof now.

Comment: @duplode I have added a new answer with a hopefully more rigorous attempt at a proof.